# Why won't Jenkins recognise Java on Mac?

Tags: macos, maven, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on my Mac and tried running my first Maven job.
In the build section of this Hello-Maven there was a line I added, namely:

`java -cp target/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.learningjenkins.App`

When running the build it failed with the following message:`The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`

I checked if everything was set using brew, attempting another Java install, although I went through this step already.

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/manifests/18.0.1.1
Already downloaded: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4d93238975eaa627e8bac389f9c2252e4f7613b17ed75cef42cc01352dbac4e0--openjdk-18.0.1.1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/blobs/sha256:820101dd1b10fa32cb7b4906aa994ab9c3679260c3e8758dc85f9c5afe57a9f7
Already downloaded: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4a1a2c311c743560b230dd7dbec99969f8c7dfaecfc734710440b075a408a6b1--openjdk--18.0.1.1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling openjdk 
==> Pouring openjdk--18.0.1.1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem was lying in front of my eyes.

```
Already downloaded: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4d93238975eaa627e8bac389f9c2252e4f7613b17ed75cef42cc01352dbac4e0--openjdk-18.0.1.1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/blobs/sha256:820101dd1b10fa32cb7b4906aa994ab9c3679260c3e8758dc85f9c5afe57a9f7
Already downloaded: /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4a1a2c311c743560b230dd7dbec99969f8c7dfaecfc734710440b075a408a6b1--openjdk--18.0.1.1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling openjdk 
==> Pouring openjdk--18.0.1.1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
**For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.**
```

Simply create the symlink by typing the following command.

`sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Last build ran successfully.